# Recursive select Mysql

Tags: mysql, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have one table with example data:

```
+----+---------+
| id | rede_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       0 |
|  2 |      38 |
|  3 |       1 |
| 38 |       1 |
| 40 |       1 |
| 41 |      38 |
| 42 |      38 |
| 43 |      40 |
```

`rede_id` means what id some person belongs to. Its a network system.

For example, if I need to check network of `id=1`, the results needs to be like:

```
+----+---------+
| id | rede_id |
+----+---------+
|  3 |       1 |
| 38 |       1 |
| 40 |       1 |
| 41 |      38 |
| 42 |      38 |
| 40 |       1 |
```

And if `rede_id` of someone is '41' or '42' needs to be on results to. Goes to infinite. 
I can have N `rede_id` with my `id`, N `rede_id` with some `id` that belongs to me and infinite... I need to get all results.

I don't know how to do that... Sincerely no I ideia.

Comment: Where's you query?????

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0 now supports recursive queries, documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive

Before MySQL 8.0, there's no easy solution for querying this type of data.

There are alternative ways of storing the data, to make it easier to query.

See also:

- [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)
- https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data